# Webscraping LinkedIn with python, selenium, and beautiful soup while logged in and accessing accounts

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm at the point where my script gets to a search page of profiles on LinkedIn, but I'm not sure how to actually access the profiles. LinkedIn is saying "You don't have access to this profile -- The profiles of members who are outside your network have limited visibility. To access more member profiles, continue to grow your network". I thought LinkedIn profiles were public so where in the html of a search result page can I find a link to the public profile? If anyone with more experience than me has any tips I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn really don't like people scraping their site so it could be that you are getting blocked by them or they have other things in place to prevent your efforts.

Check out https://www.linkedin.com/robots.txt to see what they allow you to scrap, and what they don't. It's not much they allow tbh.